# Moving object with forward is multiplying instead of adding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to move an object forward a specific distance from a start point in space. The start point does not have a forward vector, so I need to compute one from the start point to (0,0,0).

I can successfully compute a new start point with the correct forward vector, however when I use it to move an object it multiplies the move distance instead of adding it.

```
// "start" is actually a raycast hit point, but am using a Vector3 here for simplicity
float moveDistance = 2;
Vector3 start      = new Vector3 (0, 0, 3);
Vector3 center     = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
Vector3 fwd        = start - center;
myObject.position  = start + fwd * moveDistance;

Debug.Log (fwd);               //returns: (0.0, 0.0, 0.3)
Debug.Log (myObject.position); //returns: (0.0, 0.0, 9.0)
```

The result is myObject.position = 0, 0, 9 // multiplying moveDistance

And the desired result is = 0, 0, 5 // adding moveDistance

The result does have a forward vector, but it's multiplying instead of adding distance. When I do the same calculation for myObject.position using the forward vector of a gameobject, it adds the distance.

Comment: I have doubts that this is your actual code because there there are compilation errors in it. `Vector3` does not have a `transform` property. I'm guessing that your issue is an order of operations problem with this expression: `start.transform.position + fwd * distanceToMove`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that vectors have both direction and magnitude. Multiplying a vector by a scalar will multiply each of its components. If `fwd` is (0,0,3), multiplying it by 2 will yield (0,0,6). To get a vector in the same direction with `moveDistance` length, you could normalize it first:

```
myObject.position = start + fwd.normalized * moveDistance;
```

(Personally, I would rather normalize the vector before assigning it to `fwd`, but that's up to you.)

You can always separate the direction and magnitude parts of a vector, which makes it easier to work with them separately:

```
Vector3 move = <some vector>
Vector3 moveDir = move.normalized;  //a normalized vector has length 1
float moveDist = move.magnitude;    //move = moveDir * moveDist
```

Comment: Thanks rutter! I had no idea either of those two things were possible. This will come in very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
float distanceToMove = 2;
Vector3 start = new Vector3 (0, 0, 3);
Vector3 center = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
Vector3 fwd = (center - start).normalized;
myObject.position = start + fwd * distanceToMove;
Debug.Log (myObject.position);
```

Comment: Using "fwd = transform.forward;" gets the forward vector from the object that the script is running on. Instead, I need to find a forward vector from the start point to the 0,0,0 origin of the world.

Comment: Create a forward vector like so:
Vector3 fwd = (start - center).normalized;

Then use the vector like so:
myObject.position = start + fwd * distanceToMove;

Comment: I see what is going on.  Subtract the start from the center, so you have your forward vector calculation like this: Vector3 fwd = (center - start).normalized;